# Connect to wifi works only without password (Problem around WPA security)

Tags: esp32, wifi

I have an ESP32 Joy-it - SBC NodeMCU-ESP32 that should be use with board "ESP32 Dev Module". IDE says : Chip is ESP32-D0WDQ6 (revision v1.0).

Website product: https://joy-it.net/en/products/SBC-NodeMCU-ESP32

When I make a wifi scan, I find my AP, but if I connect with SSID + Password (both WPA (Internet box router - Freebox Crystal France) and WPA2 Personal (Xiaomi A2 Lite)), it doesn't work.

So I tried to make an AP without password on my phone, and ESP32 can connect without problem.

To do that, I used the default sketch "Wifi -> Wifi Client". My SSID and my password contain only letters/numbers (Only ASCII chars).

I tried to burn the bootloader, but nothing change.

I am using :

- IDE Arduino 2.2.1
- esp32 by espressif 2.0.14

Does somebody have an idea ?

Comment: `I tried to burn the bootloader` ... what does that mean?

Comment: Click on `Tools` -> `Burn bootloader` in Arduino IDE GUI :)

Comment: Have you tried older esp32 core?

Answer (score 1):

Solution, I'm using an old Freebox, which has only Open or WPA security,

Just add : `WiFi.setMinSecurity(WIFI_AUTH_WPA_PSK);` to allow connection to my router.

For people with *WEP* security, just use `WIFI_AUTH_WEP`

Comment: *"which has only Open or **WPA** security" ... `WIFI_AUTH_WEP`*.  You meant "open or *WEP*" right?

Comment: In fact, I copy paste line before move minmal security to wpa, my bad